# REST API URI Design

Tags: rest

I need to develop a REST API and I have doubts about the URI design.

**Scenario:**

1 - I’m developing one REST interface to a set of services.

2 - each service is divided from the logical point of view in several parts ( not resources).

3 – each resource can be accessed in two ways "A" and "B"

**What is the most appropriate URI design:**

/service1/part1/resource?{A|B}

/service1,part1,resource?{A|B}

Answer (score 0):

While either URL structure will work, of the choices you listed /service1/part1/resource?{A|B} is far more typical, and has the highest chance of working with common REST API consumption tools, being intuitively understood by developers, etc. The meaning of forward slashes is actually defined in the URI standard (RFC 1630 I think) and relative URIs will only work with forward slashes.

Comment: when using  GET /service1/part1/resource?{A|B} that means that GET /service1 should returns a list of services ? That it not the case. Thus should i use /service1/part1/resource?{A|B}  or /service1,part1,resource?{A|B}

Answer (score 0):

This one is better:

```
/service1/part1/resource?{A|B}
```

as it emphasizes hierarchy (thanks to slashes).

Also "the ways resources are accessed" are usually pronounced using HTTP verbs (such as GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD etc.). If this is what you meant by "ways", you should definitely stick to HTTP verbs.

Comment: But service1/part1 is not one hierarchy. I read that "Put punctuation characters in path variables to avoid implying hierarchy where
none exists: /parent/child1;child2" So if part1 is not a child of service1. Service1 is divided in several parts the URI should be /service1,part1,resource?{A|B} ?

Comment: @JSV: Any source for that (I am asking about "_Put punctuation characters in path variables to avoid implying hierarchy where none exists: /parent/child1;child2_")? Please also note that semicolon is **not** the same as comma - the semicolon is reserved for special, schema-dependent uses, eg. to separate _param_ - as opposed to _query_ - from the _path_ (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396.html).

Comment: @JSV: Also this does not need to mimic the server architecture, it just _should_ represent the logical structure in the REST API, so even if you do not have such structure on the server, it is better to present it as such, showing logical groupings of the resources.